# MS Access to Tsql: What is Asc(UCase(String)) - 64?

Tags: sql-server-2008, t-sql, ms-access

Does anyone have any idea what this Asc function is doing (-64)?  Thanks again in advance.

Access - **IIF(Trim(NZ(MCATw)) = "", 0, Abs(Asc(UCase(MCATw)) -64)) as MCATwNo**

I don't understand what the -64 is doing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's probably converting the first letter of a string to a numeric value 1-26.  The upper case letters A - Z have ASCII values of 65 - 90, so `ASC("A")` becomes 65, and 65 - 64 is 1.  Thus A - Z becomes 1 - 26.  Assuming that `MCATw` is a string, `ASC` will only apply to the first character.

Comment: Thanks.. That makes alot of sense...  Here is my TSQL equivalent: **Case When MCATw IS Null then 0 else ASCII(MCATw) -64 end as MCATwNo,**   Am I missing something?

Comment: Had to change to upper case: ** Case When MCATw IS Null then 0 else Abs(ASCII(UPPER(MCATw) -64) end as MCATwNo,**

Comment: @sjackson5280: Looks pretty good.  The only technicality is that `case when MCATw is null` is only turning `null` into `0`, but `TRIM(NZ(MCATw)) = ""`, will convert `null`, or blank, or any number of spaces into `0` as well.  You can do the same thing with `CASE WHEN NULLIF(RTRIM(LTRIM(MCATw)), '') IS NULL ... `